# php/mysql switch from mysql to mysqli or pdo, possible to do gradually

Tags: php, mysql, refactoring, pdo, mysqli

I have a web app that uses a lot of mysql_query calls--mainly because I found these in tutorials and the other places I learned how to run queries. Many people keep suggesting I switch to mysqli as mysql will disappear at some point, however, I've read that making this switch is a lot harder than adding an i at the end and requires rewriting all your code.

If I ask is the switch worth it, I imagine almost everyone will say yes since sticking with mysql seems to be a minority point of view.  So my my question is, is it possible to switch to mysqli incrementally, ie gradually update calls or pages as they are written, or is it better to freeze the old site and redo the whole thing as an all mysqli or pdo site.  When I say better, I taking into consideration all the work and costs involved in redoing the whole site.  Obviously, there is an attraction to allocating resources to new features and things on the site, rather than redoing things that work fine using the old mysql.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from a notice from PHP they wont be officially deprecating the `mysql_*` extension till at least PHP 5.5/6.0 so you have some time to rewrite your script before those function are completely gone or E_DEPRECATED errors start appearing. http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799

Perhaps if your code is spaghetti and not organised, then its time for a recode/refactoring. MVC is great as with controller models all query's are in one place & the database connection/CRUD's are in a single object property.

Comment: My experience with frameworks is they make sense for the programmer who sets it up, but if they are not well known standards, they create problems for new team members or others who need to work on them and do not know or like the framework  Is there a good standard one?  Also, is there really a way to totally separate logic from dbase access from markup?  I already have main markup separate but for distinguishing Comment from Comments and things like that it seems you always end up with if thens that mix markup with logic.

Answer (score 1):

If i was in your situation, i would take it as an opportunity to improve the application's architecture in its entirety.

You should start by separating the code, which deals only with DB interaction, from the rest of application. The best way would be to move towards  something like a [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)-like structures.

At that point switching to PDO or MySQLi will be a simple task.

There is no need to go all the way to MVC, but as you separate the different responsibilities of application: presentation logic, templating, routing, business logic, data access logic, etc. , you will end up something vaguely resembling MVC.

Answer (score 0):

First point about mysql adaptation. The good choice was to use some own adapter/wrapper initially. For example wrote class MyMysql with query(), rowCount(), eth methods. And there wouldn't be question about switching between mysql/mysqli/pdo at this moment.

Second point about switching. It's no too much difference between mysql and mysqli. Yes it's more than use "i" letter at the end of words but most of queries are very similar. At my memory there is no mysql_fetch_assoc equivalent for example (but there is mysql_fetch_array for this). May be it will be harder than use regular patterns for "mysql"->"mysqli" but isn't too hard. So don't be feared mysqli - it's logical continue of mysql driver.